# usage of require_POST in django

Tags: django

I wanna know is there a usage or security tip to use required-post or require-get decorators in django?

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_GET, require_POST
```

Answer (score 1):

[**`@require_GET`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_GET), and [**`@require_POST`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_POST) are special cases of [**`@require_http_methods(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_http_methods). These enforce that you can only call a view with certain HTTP methods.

The HTTP protocol specifies that requests that "safe methods", for example a GET request [should *not* have side effects <sup>[rfc-editor.org]</sup>](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-safe-methods):

> Request methods are considered "safe" if their defined semantics are essentially read-only; i.e., the client does not request, and does not expect, any state change on the origin server as a result of applying a safe method to a target resource.
>
> (…)
>
> Of the request methods defined by this specification, the GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, and TRACE methods are defined to be safe.

This thus means that you should not create, update, remove, etc. records with a GET request for example. A "*search spider*" for example will normally assume that a GET request is safe. If you have a view that deletes an item through a GET request, then the spider might accidentally remove an entry.

By using such decorators, you thus require the requests to have a certain HTTP method.

Comment: The trouble with these decorators is that they return a blank page upon error, which is not very user-friendly. In contrast, running `raise PermissionDenied()` displays some text to the user, which can be customised.

Comment: @Flimm: `PermissionDenied` violates the HTTP protocol, since that basically says, you are not allowed to see this, whereas restricting the method, means "it is simply not an option". As for the response, it will return 405 (method not allowed). The browser can freely choose how to render that, but normally it will indeed show a blank page, since that is an application error, not a permission error.